# Find the coefficient of $x^{16}$ in expansion of $(x^2+5x+6)^4(x^3+6x^2+11x+6)^3$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the coefficient of $x^{16}$ in expansion of $(x^2+5x+6)^4(x^3+6x^2+11x+6)^3$.

[image]
I simplified the expression and it turned out to be $(x+3)^7(x+2)^7(x+1)^3$. Now I'm stuck. I only know how to deal with 2 terms but there are 3 over here. I would appreciate a hint. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry mate, typing mistake

Comment: From those three terms, how can you get $x^{16}$: $7 + 7 + 2$, $7 + 6 + 3$ and $6 + 7 + 3$, only three ways. So you just need to calculate the coefficients for each of those combinations.

Comment: I did not get that. Sorry im new to this topic

Comment: Oh i get it now. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Considering $f(x) = (x+3)^7(x+2)^7(x+1)^3$

In expanded form, the sum of roots of this polynomial would be

$$S = \frac{-b}{a} $$

Here , $b$ would be the coefficient of $x^{16}$, and $a$ the coefficient of $x^{17}$[This is a standard result for any polynomial, that sum of roots is negative of coefficient of second highest power divided by coefficient of highest power (Can be 0)]

Now, $a = 1$ (Easy to check)

Hence, Coefficient of $x^{16} = -S = -((-3)*7+(-2)*7 +(-1)*3) = 38 $

**Approach 2**

You have $f(x) = (x+3)^7(x+2)^7(x+1)^3$

You can obtain $x^{16}$ by the following cases:

1) $x^7$ from $(x+3)^7$ , $x^7$ from $(x+2)^7$ , $x^2$ from $(x+1)^3$

2) $x^7$ from $(x+3)^7$ , $x^6$ from $(x+2)^7$ , $x^3$ from $(x+1)^3$

3) $x^6$ from $(x+3)^7$ , $x^7$ from $(x+2)^7$ , $x^3$ from $(x+1)^3$

From

1) 7C7*7C7*3C2 ,

2) 7C6 *(3) *7C7*3C3 ,

3) 7C7*7C6 *(2) *3C3

Adding these , we get Coefficient $= 38$

Comment: Answer is coming 44 from the method @Simon S told

Comment: We need to add all the 1's also and there are total 6

Comment: You're factorization is  wrong, $f(x) = (x+4)^4(x+3)^3(x+2)^3(x+1)^7$.. I assumed your factorization and got this answer

Comment: Mine is correct, bro

Comment: $x^2 + 5x + 4 = (x+1)(x+4)$ and $x^3 + 6x^2 + 11x + 6 = (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$

Comment: Someone edited it. Its 6 at the end

Comment: I edited it. Please check answer.now

Comment: Cool.. i'll make apt edits

Comment: Also, pls check the image ive uploaded in the question itself.

Comment: @user354545 Not that it matters much, but the $+4$ was in the original question as you posted it. It was not introduced by *someone*'s edit. That can be easily seen in the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2003055/revisions).

Comment: O im Sorry then. I dont remember.